# Manual Ember computed property not working while helper properties do

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

I have the following controller with many computed properties, most of which utilize helper functions. All of those work flawlessly when referenced in the template. However, the two manually-constructed computed properties fail if I add them to my template because the properties they reference are undefined when the function is run the first time. I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` from numeral.js because if it. What's wrong with the way I've constructed it? Why are the computed properties built with the helpers working fine referencing the same underlying model data?

```
  AdvisorAccountsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
    open:          Ember.computed.filterBy "model", "status", "Open"
    pending:       Ember.computed.filterBy "model", "status", "Pending"
    openValues:    Ember.computed.mapBy "open", "value"
    pendingValues: Ember.computed.mapBy "pending", "value"
    openCount:     Ember.computed.alias "open.length"
    pendingCount:  Ember.computed.alias "pending.length"
    openTotal:     Ember.computed.sum "openValues"
    pendingTotal:  Ember.computed.sum "pendingValues"
    showPending:   Ember.computed.gt "pendingCount", 0
    openTotalUSD: (-> numeral(@get "openTotal").format "$0,0.00").property "openTotal"
    pendingTotalUSD: (-> numeral(@get "pendingTotal").format "$0,0.00").property "pendingTotal"
```

I think what's happening is that the model is still resolving by the time this gets fired. That's not a problem for the sum properties because the resulting value isn't being relied on by something else, and they can resolve in their own time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
openCount: function(){
    return open && open.length;
    }.property('open.length')
```

so this way you will try to access `length` of `open` only if `open` is defined and "trueish".

Comment: Thanks. I knew I could add code to check for values, but I was hoping to avoid that by relying on full model resolution before the controller takes over. It turns out that it's a problem with not being able to be sure of that rather than with my computed properties per se. But this is a useful approach to checking.